# foreach with multiple DictionaryEntry

Tags: c#, foreach

I am trying to write to a ListView using the contents of 3 three already existing resx files. Using the following loop with only one of the files yields close to what I want but I need is to use the same loop with multiple DictionaryEntrys. What I am trying to do looks like this..

```
ResXResourceReader rdr0 = new ResXResourceReader(textPath1.Text + ".resx");
ResXResourceReader rdr1 = new ResXResourceReader(textPath1.Text + ".es.resx");
ResXResourceReader rdr2 = new ResXResourceReader(textPath1.Text + ".fr.resx");

foreach ((DictionaryEntry d in rdr0) && (DictionaryEntry e in rdr1))
{
    string[] row = { d.Key.ToString(), d.Value.ToString(), e.Value.ToString() };
    var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
    listResx.Items.Add(listViewItem);
}
```

Comment: Either you merge them into one and iterate over (read the zip answer), or if they're all equally long you may for loop over them and get the correct index from each, the last one would be considered a "HACK!!!" though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `foreach` keyword cannot do that.

Instead, you can use the LINQ [`.Zip()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx):

```
foreach(var item in rdr0.Zip(rdr1, (d, e)
         => new [] { d.Key.ToString(), d.Value.ToString(), e.Value.ToString() }))
```

Comment: Nice solution. Never heard of Zip before

Comment: Receiving the error...Resources.ResXResourceReader' does not contain a definition for 'Zip' and no extension method 'Zip' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Resources.ResXResourceReader' could be found. Is the .Zip method disagreeing with the fact that its using ResxResourceReaders?

Comment: @RobbyBelliveau: I forgot that they aren't generic.  Add `.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()` to both collections.

Comment: @JohnMc: It's new to .Net 4.0.

Comment: @SLaks my implementation could be wrong but it is still giving me System.Linq.Queryable.Zip is a method which is not valid in the given context.

Comment: @RobbyBelliveau: What did you write?

Comment: @RobbyBelliveau: `.Cast()` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`.